# DataDynamics To ActiveReport9

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, activereports

I am bit new to Active Reports..
I want to Migrate Repots from datadynamics to Active Report9.

There are some old code with data types ReportRuntime, ReportDefinition, ReportPreview
which are inheriting from Datadynamics.Reports.

Q1. What are the equivalents of these keywords in ActiveReports or from which assembly I can get these data types.
Q2. Which Dll can Replace the DataDynamics.Reports.Windows.Forms.dll in ActiveReports 9.

Comment: I am not able to create a forum at http://help.gcactivereports.com/groups/forum/reporting/... Not able to login and get create forum link on above link...  how to contact the Grapecity help forums....?

Comment: You should be able to create a account by selecting the Join option. Are you getting any error when trying to create one? Please try using any other browser and see if you still face any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Since you also posted the same question on ComponentOne Support, I have provided the same response here:

If you are looking to upgrade your existing project to ActiveReports 9 then you should do it using the converter tool as suggested [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/Upgrading%20Reports.html). This should automatically take care of majority of namespace and classes in your project. For more information on changes, please see this [link](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/index.html#BreakingChanges.html).

For your information, ReportDefinition is now [PageReport](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v9~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReport.html). ReportRuntime is now [PageDocument](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v9~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.PageDocument.html).

I think ReportPreview was the viewer control available for displaying reports. So you can now use the [WinViewer](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/UsingActiveReportsWindowsFormsViewer%20.html) for this functionality. You should have "GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.v9.dll" to display the viewer control in a windows forms project.